# Steganography Error-- 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Tags: python, steganography

I am new to Steganography. Trying to do a test and i get this error:

```
 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

I have read about  binascii, but how can i make this work?

My code is this one:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from steganography.steganography import Steganography

path = "/Users/cohen/Desktop/Screenshot_030.png"
output_path = "/Users/cohen/Desktop/output_steganography.png"

text = "/Users/cohen/Desktop/test.txt"

Steganography.encode(path, output_path, text) #---here is the line with error
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'd ask the project maintainer to update their code to work with Python 3, or use it with Python 2 only.

Comment: The project currently is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: thank you! I taught that is something fishy with their code.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I also just checked. The project is not compatible with Python 3.

You can find a lot of nice simple steganography module on GitHub, especially if you want to test the LSB (Least Significant Bit) technic. For example, this one is compatible with Python 3:
https://github.com/cedricbonhomme/Stegano